# Why does zsh wait for this command to finish, while bash writes the prompt before it's done?

Tags: bash, zsh

Here's the command:

```
{ ( echo "to stdout"; echo "to stderr" >&2 ) > >(sleep 1; tee stdout.txt); } 2> >(sleep 2; tee stderr.txt >&2 )
```

And here's what I see:

zsh

```
% { ( echo "to stdout"; echo "to stderr" >&2 ) > >(sleep 1; tee stdout.txt); } 2> >(sleep 2; tee stderr.txt >&2 )
to stdout
to stderr
%
```

bash

```
$ { ( echo "to stdout"; echo "to stderr" >&2 ) > >(sleep 1; tee stdout.txt); } 2> >(sleep 2; tee stderr.txt >&2 )
$ to stdout
to stderr
```

Note that bash writes it's prompt `$` before output completes, but zsh waits for the substituted processes to complete before prompting the user `%`.

I suppose a reasonable answer might be "because that's how zsh works", but I want to know if this is documented anywhere so that I can learn more.  As a zsh user among many bash users, I try to know the differences so that I know what to expect when I say "hey run this command".

(related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53051506/1054322)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shorter example that behaves the same way in both shells.  The parent shell does not wait.

```sh
(sleep 1; echo done) > >(cat >file) &
```

With the following modification, `zsh` *will* wait, but `bash` won't:

```sh
{ (sleep 1; echo done) & } > >(cat >file)
```

A similar example is given in the `zshexpn(1)` manual under "PROCESS SUBSTITUTION". There, it mentions that the shell will wait for the asynchronous process within `{ ... }` when redirecting the output of an asynchronous process into a process substitution (which is also asynchronous, in both shells), but will not wait without the `{ ... }`.

The manual phrases the problem as

> There is an additional problem with `>(process)`; when this is attached
>   to an external command, **the parent shell does not wait for process to
>   finish and hence an immediately following command cannot rely on the
>   results being complete**.

By enclosing the asynchronous command in a compound `{ ... }`, the "extra processes here are spawned from the parent shell which will
wait for their completion."  The way that I interpret this is that the process that we redirect into with `>(...)` will be spawned from the shell whereas without `{ ... }`, it will be spawned from the job that we start as a background job (and the shell will therefore not wait for it).

An evidence for this is found if you output `$ZSH_SUBSHELL` inside the process substitution that you redirect into.  With the blocking code, it will output `1`, while with the non-blocking code, it will output `2`, showing that the output redirection is run as a sub-shell inside another sub-shell (which the main shell won't wait for).

The `bash` shell seems to handle this differently and spawns all background jobs independently of the parent shell in both cases, even though outputting `$BASH_SUBSHELL` inside the output process substitution exhibits the same behaviour as in `zsh`.

Comment: I'm in slightly over my head, but anchoring the behavior to a spot in the manual will let me learn the terminology so I can remedy that. This is great, thank you.